# My program works when run from NetBeans, but not when I run it as a JAR file

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

My program listens to a serial port, takes values from the data it hears, and updates a MySQL database with those values, using `comm.jar` in the Library. When I run my program from the NetBeans IDE, it works fine. But I need to distribute it, so I used NetBeans to create a .jar file.

When I run my program from that .jar file, it doesn't work - it inserts `null` values in the database. What might be causing this problem? How can I get my program to run properly both in NetBeans and in the distributable .jar form?

Comment: can you please post some code/ logs ?

Answer (score 0):

comm.jar should be placed in:
%JAVA_HOME%/lib, 
%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/ext,

win32com.dll should be placed in:
%JAVA_HOME%/bin, 
%JAVA_HOME%/jre/bin,
%windir%System32,

javax.comm.properties should be placed in:
%JAVA_HOME%/lib, 
%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib